# What is "which was Mr Grainger's cabin" in this sentence ?

Tags: grammar

The sentence is:
**In her panic she couldn't remember which was Mr Grainger's cabin.**

"In her panic" is an adjective that describes the pronoun "she" but what is "which was Mr Grainger's cabin" ? Is it an adverbial that modifies "remember" ?

Comment: "Which" is a determiner of the noun phrase. A stripped down sentence with a similar structure is "she remember the cabin". Both  "The cabin" and "which was Mr. Grainger's cabin" are noun phrases.

Answer (score 1):

The clause "which was Mr. Grainger's cabin" is subordinate.   It acts as the *direct object* of "remember".

If the clause were not subordinate, it would be interrogative: "Which was Mr. Grainger's cabin?"   As stands, it is a nominative clause, a content clause.   In either case, we can regard "which" as a substantive adjective or a pronoun, acting as the subject of its clause.   "Was" is the verb.   "Mr. Grainger's cabin" is the verb's argument, a predicate nominative subject complement.

As a subordinate, it does not represent a question.   It represents a fact, something that happens to be the related question's answer.